# Get maximum value conditional on another value which might be missing

Tags: r, if-statement, max, warnings, mutate

I'd like to get the maximum date within a group where another column has a specific value. In the specific example, I'd like to extract the maximum `date` of all dates within a `group` where `status == "inactive"`. If there are no dates where status==inactive, NA should be returned.

I get the following code working, but also get a warning message which I do not fully understandy why:

```
# Create sample data
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  date = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01")),
  status = c("active", "inactive", "active", "active")
)

# Mutate data to get maximum date by group for rows where status is "inactive" 
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(max_date = max(date[status=="inactive"]))


df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(max_date = dplyr::if_else(any(status=="inactive"),
                       max(date[status=="inactive"]),
                       NA_Date_))
```

This returns the following warning message:

```
Problem while computing `max_date = dplyr::if_else(...)`.
ℹ no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
ℹ The warning occurred in group 2: group = "B".
```

The second approach correctly returns the NA values, but why do I get the warning message as the `max(date)`-function should only be used/executed when the condition of the `if_else` statement is met? Of course I could mute or ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Using `if/else` makes it work. `if_else` evaluates both `true` and `false` before assessing the `condition` (as explained by Darren Tsai), which explains why you get a warning.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(max_date = if(any(status == "inactive")) max(date[status=="inactive"]) else NA)

  group date       status   max_date  
  <chr> <date>     <chr>    <date>    
1 A     2022-01-01 active   2022-02-01
2 A     2022-02-01 inactive 2022-02-01
3 B     2022-03-01 active   NA        
4 B     2022-04-01 active   NA
```

Comment: With `if_else(condition, true, false)`, `true` and `false` parts are both evaluated before `condition`. You can check this example: `if_else(FALSE, log('a'), 1)` and `if(FALSE) log('a') else 1`. The former gets an error but the latter works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fmax`

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   mutate(max_date = fmax(date[status == "inactive"])[1], .by = 'group')
```

-output

```
group       date   status   max_date
1     A 2022-01-01   active 2022-02-01
2     A 2022-02-01 inactive 2022-02-01
3     B 2022-03-01   active       <NA>
4     B 2022-04-01   active       <NA>
```